# How to send a serialized object byte stream over http rest service

Tags: java, rest, serialization, compression

I've a restful service endpoint exposes the object array as a Jackson Json serialized object [mediatype.application_json] which is then Deserialized by the rest clients to retrieve the data.

In many instances, the Array length goes beyond 30K rows(roughly over 5MB), in such cases the serialization time lag appears more than processing time.

So, we used the msgPack compression method which gives better output than java serialization and much better than json to serialize/deserialize the object.

But I couldn't find a way to send the byte stream through a Jersey Restful Service.

I've tried with the application/octet-stream to get this to work, but wasn't successful.

Any help or guidance on this is appreciated

Thanks